# Standard WordPress gallery - Possible to open image in page?

Tags: gallery

I have the standard gallery which works OK. It is configured so that when someone clicks a thumbnail it opens a larger version (at the moment- the full sized version).

The issue is that when clicking an image, it opens the .jpg directly in the browser window like a hyperlink to a new page, so to get back to the gallery button you need to click the 'back' button in your browser but this is quite difficult for some mobile users.

Is there a way, where on clicking an image, it opens it within the website (with the same theme, menus etc.) so the user can click the gallery menu item again to get back to the page they were on?

In an ideal world it would be nice to have a 'back' button below the image but that may not be possible with this gallery.

I'm not looking for alternative galleries because I've looked and none of them satisfy me from an SEO perspective like the standard WP one does.

Comment: Hey Edit Gallery Setting Link to Attachment Page then the gallery image open in new page within the theme template

Comment: @amitrh Thanks for that. I remember now I have seen that before but I think the reason I didn't use it was that in the attachment page, the picture is very small. Is there a way I can increase it's size? I tried modifying the medium and large sizes properties in the media settings but it didn't change the images on the page.